# Ao finalizar o script com "Ctrl+C" (KeyboardInterrupt) não fecha Selenium o Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

Estou utilizando o selenium para manipular uma pagina, ao executar o script ele abre o firefox, mas o que eu queria fazer é o seguinte, se acontecer qualquer problema no script ou se o usuário finalizar, quero que o firefox feche também.

Tentei varias coisas como:

Usar o exit:

```
def __exit__(self):
    self.fechaAba()
```

Ou o del:

```
def __del__(self):
    self.fechaAba()
```

A função que estou utilizando é esta, ela esta funcionando, utilizo ela nas exceptions para fechar o firefox quando da erro.

```
def fechaAba(self):
    try:
        self.__driver.driver.close()
    except:
        setLog("Firefox ja finalizado")
```

Mas por exemplo se aperto Ctrl + C para finalizar o script ele não fecha o firefox, o mais perto que eu cheguei foi utilizando o atexit:

```
import atexit

    def __init__(self):
        atexit.register(self.exit_handler)

    def exit_handler(self):
        self.fechaAba()
```

Ele apresenta a mensagem "Firefox ja finalizado", mas o firefox continua aberto:

```
KeyboardInterrupt

[2017-09-28 15:16:41]: Firefox ja finalizado

[2017-09-28 15:16:42]: Firefox ja finalizado
```

Quando eu uso o driver.close() ele entra na exception e apresenta a mensagem "Firefox ja finalizado", ou seja ele não conseguiu executar o comando, e quando eu uso quit o efeito é parecido, ele executa normalmente o quit(Não entra na exception), mas o firefox continua aberto.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import atexit

class WhatsappAPI(object):

    driver = None

    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__"
        atexit.register(self.exit_handler)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")

    def comeca_acao(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            print "ok"

    def exit_handler(self):
        print "exit_handler"
        self.driver.quit()

    def __exit__(self):
        print "__exit__"
        self.driver.quit()

    def __del__(self):
        print "__del__"
        self.driver.quit()


w = WhatsappAPI()
w.comeca_acao()
```

Resultado:

```
teste.py
__init__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Futurotec\Documents\futurofone_chat\branch\v3.12\_externo\WhatsappBot - Instalador\Final\WhatsappWebAPI\teste.py", line 34, in <module>
    w.comeca_acao()
  File "C:\Users\Futurotec\Documents\futurofone_chat\branch\v3.12\_externo\WhatsappBot - Instalador\Final\WhatsappWebAPI\teste.py", line 17, in comeca_acao
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
exit_handler
__del__
```

Quando aparece no terminal "`__init__`" ele abre o firefox, quando aperto ctrl c o firefox continua aberto, o que eu quero é que o firefox feche ao aperta ctrl c ou quando entrar em qualquer exception. Nas exceptions já funciona, mas quando aperto ctrl c não.

Comment: Após testes percebi que o problema realmente parece ser ou com o Sellenium ou com o geckodriver (provavelmente só ocorre no Windows, mas não posso afirmar). Estou tentando criar para contornar. +1 porque a duvida será muito útil para muitos visitantes.

Comment: tente utilizar a biblioteca Pyinput para verificar a sequência de teclas pressionadas, caso positivo para "Cltr+C" vc utilizar o webdriver.quit() | firefox.quit()

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta tratar a exceção KeyboardInterrupt quando for executar o programa, ex:

```
try:    
  w = WhatsappAPI()
  w.comeca_acao()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  w.driver.quit()
  print "Ate logo!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode matar o firefox independentemente do Selenium, com a consequência de que você mata o processo por completo, não apenas a aba que seu script tenha iniciado. Além de não fechar o processo de forma "limpa".

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im firefox.exe")
```

/f manda encerrar à força. /im faz o taskkill identificar o programa pelo nome.

Comment: O problema que esta solução irá fechar todas as instâncias do firefox, e o problema em questão que ele não consegue realizar o comando depois da finalização do script, então acredito que este comando não será executado também.

Comment: Este código pode ser colocado dentro de um [tratador de saída](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html). Ainda vai fechar o firefox por completo, mas vai rodar quando você apertar ctrl c.